# how do I parse this url in ubuntu

Tags: bash, scripts, lubuntu, url

I have a url like this

https://vimeo.com/library/videos/angular-fire-theme/table-of-contents

In a bash script I want to parse this url so that I get the text 'angular-fire-theme'

The urls are consistent in format, i.e they have table-of-contents at the end and the format in front.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command:

```
echo 'https://vimeo.com/library/videos/angular-fire-theme/table-of-contents' | cut -d / -f6
```

This splits the URL (taken from standard input, hence the `echo`) by `/` and outputs the sixth field. (first field is "https:", second is "", third is "vimeo.com", etc). Note that this is dependent on the number of slashes before the format ("angular-fire-theme" in your example) not changing.

More ways to do it:

```
echo 'https://vimeo.com/library/videos/angular-fire-theme/table-of-contents' | sed 's_.*/\(.*\)/table-of-contents_\1_'
```

This finds the part of the URL immediately before "table-of-contents" and outputs it.

```
echo 'https://vimeo.com/library/videos/angular-fire-theme/table-of-contents' | sed 's_.*/videos/\(.*\)/.*_\1_'
```

This finds the part of the URL immediately after "videos" and outputs it.